# How to pick up on streamlit text area (Command + Enter) action?

Tags: python, streamlit

So, I have a text_area in the app. A user enters something there and then press the button below "submit". Now I can use the click of a Button as an action callback like below:

```
with st.container():
        query = st.text_area("Ask a question here:", height= 100, key= "query_text")
        button = st.button("Submit", key="button")
    if button:
        with st.spinner('Fetching Answer...'): 
            response = custom_qa.qa.run(query)
```

And run another piece of code tied to that action.

But the text area also has Command+Enter option (bottom right) for use to enter the text. How do I catch that to initiate the same action as Button clicked,  as text_area doesn't return any value concerning that.

[image]

Comment: You can use `if query:`

Comment: damn right. I missed I had a way to get feedback from text. Thanks a ton